# spacemacs resume file filter

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

In spacemacs one could do `SPC s l` to resume the last search.

Is there any similar keybinding to resume the last listing of project files?  I often do `SPC p f` and reduce the result by a pattern, pick one file and operate on it, but then I would like to go back to that filtered list of files without having to repeat the `SPC p f pattern`, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SPC rl` resumes the last helm listing, so it will re-display anything that was listed (including project files, buffers, etc)

It's `helm-resume`